# Command line, how to enter to the first directory

Tags: cmd

Does anyone know how I can go into the first directory in some other directory via the cmd on Windows?
For example I enter into the "abc" directory:

```
cd abc
```

Then I don't know the name of the first folder in the "abc" directory but I know that I need to enter in that first folder.

```
cd %first% (for example).
```

Comment: The "dir" command lists all the files and folders in the current folder (listed alphabetically) then you can read the name of the first folder and use the "cd" command to enter it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can do the job, create a file named cd2first.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
CD abc  
FOR /D %%a IN (*) DO (
  CD %%a
  GOTO :EOF
)
```

Explanation:

1. Change directory to abc from CWD.
2. FOR /D for each directory in the new current directory, change to the first subdirectory.
3. GOTO :EOF, goto to the End Of batch File.